# Java reflexión acceso métodos subclase desde superclase

Tags: java, herencia, clase-abstracta, reflection

Tengo una superclase abstracta llamada Registro. De esta clase heredan varias, A, B, C, etc...

```
public abstract class Registro {
    public void funcionQueNosInteresa() {
        //Aqui es donde obtenemos los atributos de la subclase
        for(Field declaredField : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            //Aqui queremos ejecutar el metodo get para cada atributo
        }
    }
}

public class A extends Registro {
    private String x;
    private String y;

    private String getX(){
        return x;
    }

    private String getY(){
        return y;
    }
}
```

Mi intención es desde este método (funcionQueNosInteresa) en la superclase abstracta recorrer todos los atributos de la subclase llamando el método por defecto getX para poder obtener el valor de estos atributos. Se que existe la función getMethods/getMethod que nos retorna todos los métodos o el especificado a través del nombre y la definición de parámetros, respectivamente. Pero no me interesa, ya que es necesario saber el nombre exacto de la función.

Me gustaría saber si es posible a través del atributo (field) poder obtener el método por defecto get de este, sin saber el nombre del método.

Se que se puede hacer alguna chapuza del estilo, concateno "get" + "nombreDelAtributo", pero estoy intentando buscar una solución mas elegante. Estuve intentando buscar una solución a través de la reflexión de java utilizando algo llamado "accessor", pero sin éxito.

Muchas gracias y disculpen si existe algún error, es mi primer post! ;)

Comment: Buenas. No sé si he entendido bien tu cuestión, pero no podrías sobrescribir funcionQueNosInteresa en las clases hijas y hacer uso así de polimorfismo?

Comment: Si que podría, el problema es que la funcionQueNosInteresa procesa el valor de estos atributos y hace bastantes mas cosas. Si sobrescribiera la función en cada clase heredada tendría bastante redundancia de código, cosa que no nos interesa. Muchas gracias de todos modos!! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A diferencia de los *properties* en C#, en Java no existe un "método por defecto" para modificar o acceder a los atributos. Los beans y los *getters/setters* se basan en convención (todo el mundo los hace iguales), el lenguaje no los soporta específicamente.

Así pues, la opción que tienes es leer la lista de campos, calcular como se llamaría el *getter* correspondiente (tampoco es tan difícil, poner la primera letra en mayúscula y añadir `get` o `is` delante) y ver si existe el susodicho método.

Dicho lo dicho, en general desaconsejo usar *reflection* por la cantidad de efectos secundarios que puede tener. En tu caso, veo dos opciones:

- Dependerá de tu modelo, pero si lo único que quieres es evitar duplicidad igual te interesa pasar a composición en vez de herencia. ¿Tiene sentido mover `funcionQueNosInteresa` a una clase distinta?
- Si seguimos usando herencia, cambia a:

  ```
  public abstract class Registro {
    protected abstract Map<String, Object> getDatos();

    public void funcionQueNosInteresa() {
      //Aqui es donde obtenemos los atributos de la subclase
      Map<String, Object> datos = this.getDatos();
      for(String clave : datos) {
        Object dato = datos.get(clave);
        //Aqui la lógica.
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  que te permite un mejor control de la información.

Answer (score 1):

En este aspecto Java funciona por convención: getters y setters han de ser creados explícitamente en la clase y la firma ha de ser siempre así:

```
ClaseDelAtributo "get"+ [nombre del atributo empezando con mayúscula] ()
void "set"+ [nombre del atributo empezando con mayúscula] (ClaseDelAtributo nuevo_valor)
```

Esta convención es tan fuerte que frameworks como Hibernate o Spring se basan en ella a la hora de crear objectos o inyectar dependencias, así que usar la lista que te devuelve `getClass.getMethods()` y luego filtrar los que empiezan por `"get"` o `"set"` no es tan chapuza.

De todos modos, si lo que quieres es obtener o modificar los valores, puedes acceder directamente al atributo saltándote los getters/setters, incluso aunque sean privados.

Por otro lado, veo más lógico que cada clase hija añada su propia lógica al método `funcionQueNosInteresa` y quizá no tiene por qué repetir código:

```
public abstract class Registro {
    public void funcionQueNosInteresa() {
        //Aqui es donde obtenemos los atributos de la subclase
        for(Field declaredField : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            //Aqui queremos ejecutar el metodo get para cada atributo
        }
    }
}

public class A extends Registro {
    private String x;
    private String y;

    public String getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public String getY(){
        return y;
    }

    public void funcionQueNosInteresa() {
        super.funcionQueNosInteresa(); //Código ya implementado
        //Código extra a realizar para esta clase;
    }
}
```